# Is it ok to use my edit powers to warn users of bad accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/819420/38557. The accepted answer (from 2009) is wrong, and I'm not referring to the fact that it's outdated but to the many bugs in it, reported in comments.

I can't unmark it as accepted because I'm not the OP.

Is it ethical to edit the answer and put a big warning in the first line? Something like "this answer is outdated and has a few reported bugs, see comments and other answers".

The fact that nobody did it so far (with 50 downvotes) tells me it might not be ok.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not OK. Put yourself in the answerer's shoes: how would you like someone editing a big "this is wrong!" banner into one of your answers?

Comment: Kind of what I thought, but how do I help others not use bad code?

Comment: Ensure that a better answer has been posted (if it’s not yours, upvote it), ensure that you’ve downvoted the incorrect answer(s), and optionally leave a comment on the incorrect answers pointing out *specific* problems and referencing one or more other answers that avoid those problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that would "conflict with the author's intent". Leaving a comment would be so much easier and avoid so much unnecessary confrontation.

> "I think you might've missed adding foo to bar there, would you take
>   another look?"

If you're dealing with an old answer where the author is no longer around or unresponsive, leave a comment and write your own answer.

Of course, you also have the option of exercising a downvote and moving on.

Comment: The thing is, pretty much **all** comments on the answer say it's buggy. Yet, that green checkmark tells you it's a good answer (or used to be).

Comment: @noamtm Once you come to terms with the fact that the green check **does not** necessarily reflect the quality of an answer, rather the votes do, this answer will make a lot more sense to you.

Comment: An answer being marked as the solution does not make it a good answer @noamtm . It means the OP has accepted that answer as the solution. There are plenty of answers out there with a high amount of downvotes (score of -10 or less) that are accepted and there are answers on the same question with 50+ upvotes.